# Slurm interactive mode - run pre-specified command at beginning

Tags: slurm, interactive-mode

On my cluster, I can get a shell for interactive mode if I run:

> srun -N 1 --ntasks-per-node=1 --gres=gpu:1  --pty zsh

However, on this cluster, each node that is allocated has an empty $HOME directory (without the .zshrc), which is stored on a shared drive. How can I run in interactive mode with a pre-specified command to load my .zshrc automatically on login? i.e., I would ideally want something like this

> srun -N 1 --ntasks-per-node=1 --gres=gpu:1  --pty zsh
>   **--runCommandOnLaunch='source /shared_drive/razvan/.zshrc'**

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$ZDOTDIR=/shared_drive/razvan/ srun -N 1 --ntasks-per-node=1 --gres=gpu:1 --pty zsh
```

Upon startup, Zsh will look for a startup file (`zshrc`) in `$ZDOTDIR`. (See more details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131716/start-zsh-with-a-custom-zshrc/131717)). As `srun` will, by default, export all environment variables to the remote commands it spawns, Zsh should load your RC file upon startup.